# Undeploy web application from tomcat doesn't remove the deployed directory

Tags: java, tomcat, undeploy

I am using tomcat manager commands to deploy and undeploy web applications on a tomcat server. The problem is when I try to undeploy a web application, it does remove the `.war` file from the `webapps` directory but the exploded directory doesn't get removed (the `WEB-INF/lib` folder), neither from the List Applications in the tomcat mananger.

I am on Windows and I am using Tomcat 6.0.20.

**Note:** When I tried to delete the directory manually it gave me an error saying that the file is being used by another program.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the solution, just put this in your `context.xml` file in `your_tomcat_home_directory/Config`:

```
<Context antiJARLocking="true" antiResourceLocking="true">
```

Everything works fine.

Comment: the [docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html) say: antiJARLocking is a subset of antiResourceLocking and therefore, to prevent duplicate work and possible issues, only one of these attributes should be set to true at any one time

Answer (score 0):

Try to stop your Tomcatserver(-service), then you can manually delete the exploded directory, then restart it agian.

Comment: I can't stop the tomcat service, it should be done on the fly, there are other applications running and I can't just stop them.

Answer (score 0):

I was on Windows using cygwin. Even after shutting down tomcat, I could not delete the web application folder - the command kept on returning "Device or resource busy". I noticed that the java process was still running even after I had shut down tomcat so I decided to kill it, and was able to manually delete the web application folder.